# .gradle: Directory not empty in gitlab CI

Tags: android, gradle, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Seems the gradle demons dont let the .gradle folder to be cleared before a sequential build giving the below error.

How do I make sure the gradle demons don't lock the .gradle directory and it can be deleted?

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.2.0 (a987417a)
  on xe runner eRm5EUTW
Using Shell executor...
00:00
Running on DEMU-MAC01-2.local...
00:02
rm: /Users/xx/workspace/builds/eRm5EUTW/0/xx/xx/.gradle: Directory not empty
00:25
rm: /Users/xx/workspace/builds/eRm5EUTW/0/xx/xx: Directory not empty
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Comment: have you found any way to resolve this issue  @ir2pid ?